# Firebase messaging : how to configure serverless function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin, vercel

I'm trying to set up a vercel function to handle (un)subscribe to firebase messaging. There is way less documentation of the server side of things so I'm struggling.

I believe I have the right service worker account json at `admin.json` but this code is failing with an error `FirebaseError: Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source.`

```
import admin from 'firebase-admin';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin/app';
import serviceAccount from './admin.json' assert { type: 'json' };
import { getMessaging } from 'firebase/messaging';

export default function messaging(request, response) {
    // Q1 should this be inside the function or outside?
    const app = initializeApp({
        credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
    });
    // body is a string
    let body = JSON.parse(request.body);

    if (body.action === 'subscribe') {
        // this is where the error is coming in
        return getMessaging()
            .subscribeToTopic(body.token, 'mol23-general')
            .then((res) => {
                response.status(200).json({ result: res });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('Error subscribing to topic:', error);
                response.status(500).json({ error });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

ugh. was using the wrong version of getMessaging

```
import { getMessaging } from 'firebase-admin/messaging';
```